# DeviceInformation.name displays Bluetooth version instead of name

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth, winjs

Method [Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.findAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/apps/br225434) returns Collection of [DeviceInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation). This object has property [name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.name) assigned as the Device Bluetooth Name. But instead, the property contains values such as HM-12, SPP Dev or SerialPort which I assume are names of Bluetooth protocols.

Below is the example. Please note that this code was working properly prior Windows upgrade (which version caused this is unknown)

Working on Windows 10 mobile 10.0.14393.67

Windows 10 desktop outputs correct results.

```
var rfcomm = Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm;
var sockets = Windows.Networking.Sockets;
var streams = Windows.Storage.Streams;
var deviceInfo = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation;

var cordova = require('cordova');
module.exports = {

  connService: null,
  connSocket: null,
  connWriter: null,
  connReader: null,
  connDevice: null,

  list: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      try {
        var selector =
          rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService.getDeviceSelector(
            rfcomm.RfcommServiceId.serialPort);
        var parsedDevices = [];

        deviceInfo.findAllAsync(selector, null).then(function(devices) {
          if (devices.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
              parsedDevices.push({
                id: devices[i].id,
                name: devices[i].name
              })
              successCallback(parsedDevices);
            }
          } else {
            errorCallback("No devices found.");
          }

        }, function(error) {
          errorCallback({
            error: "list",
            message: error.message
          });
        });


      } catch (ex) {
        errorCallback(ex);
      }


}, 0);
  }
}
```

Value of selector (Windows 10 mobile):

```
System.Devices.DevObjectType:=10 AND System.Devices.AepService.ProtocolId:="{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}" AND System.Devices.AepService.ServiceClassId:="{B142FC3E-FA4E-460B-8ABC-072B628B3C70}" AND System.Devices.AepService.Bluetooth.ServiceGuid:="{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}" AND System.Devices.AepService.ParentAepIsPaired:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
```

Value of selector (Windows 10 PC) - works OK

```
System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{B142FC3E-FA4E-460B-8ABC-072B628B3C70}\" AND System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.ServiceGuid:=\"{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}\" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Your selector is only looking for devices/services that match a serialPort description, which is why you are getting names like SPP Dev or Serial Port.

**Solution**

Taken from the [Windows 10 sample for BluetoothRFcommChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat/cs/Scenario1_ChatClient.xaml.cs), to find Bluetooth devices use the following AQS query:

```
// Any extra properties you need
var requestedProperties = null

// The magic happens here, "e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974" is 
//  the GUID for any Bluetooth device.
var selector = "(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}\")"

// Then run findAllAsync with these new filters
deviceInfo.findAllAsync(selector, requestedProperties).then(function(devices) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried the selector you proposed, It does not return any devices found. I have put my selector in updated post.